# Practical reasons for referencing the same type within itself?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

Other than possibly constructors, and copying/cloning. Is there a need to reference an object with the same type as itself?

e.g.

```
class TEST {
  TEST x;

  void dosomething() {
    TEST tmp;
    ...
  }

  TEST another_possible() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Quite a few. Must we enumerate *all* of them?

Comment: Anything other than a list/tree-structure would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example:

- A linked list node references the next node (and maybe previous node).
- A tree node may reference other tree nodes -- as children or as parent.
- A graph node may reference adjacent graph nodes.
- An instance may wrap another instance (e.g., [java.lang.Throwable and its cause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable%28java.lang.Throwable%29)).

Comment: A linked list is a tree, and any tree is a graph.

Comment: Yes. The first three bullets are related in concept, but differ in implementation and familiarity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it's called a recursive data type.  Example, for a tree-like data structure:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Node> Children; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a reflexive association relationship, for example.

[image]

Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit surprised that the (anti) pattern Singleton hadn't been posted yet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
[image]